# How do I construct sample-based rarefaction curves if the area (or volume) sampled is not consistent between samples?

Tags: ecology, statistics, data, biodiversity, community-ecology

My apologies if a similar question has been asked previously but I cannot find an answer.
I have data from multiple zooplankton tows from different study sites and I am trying to construct sample-based rarefaction curves for each site. So, number of samples on the x-axis, number of species on the y-axis.
However, nets were used to sample the plankton and the volume of water for each sample is not consistent.
How can I adjust the curves to account for the variability in sample volume? Can I replace the x-axis (number of samples) with the average volume of water sampled per tow?